# CSV Python Append Header after Data has been input

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file in which I have already got all the data inside and I simply just need to write the header to the file without having to rewrite the whole file.

Example before:

```
Jim Bob
Sam Ham
```

Example after:

```
FirstName LastName
------------------
Jim       Bob
Sam       Ham
```

Comment: read the file again...pre-pend the `header` and write it back

Comment: What is wrong with rewriting the whole file? What else do you think might be possible? With practically all file systems, you cannot insert an arbitrary number of bytes anywhere other than the end of the file without rewriting everything that comes after the insertion point. You may be able to hide the rewriting but it will still be there. Just go ahead and rewrite! You can delete the old file afterwards if you need the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming df is your dataframe
    `df.columns = ["First_Name", "Last_Name"`]

Comment: Was it helpful ??